# RabbitMQ throws AlreadyClosedException rather than IOException when the broker connection is lost

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm using rabbitmq java client 2.4.1 the newest version.

After a TCP connection lost, and still call a method on a channel over
this connection, a AlreadyClosedException will be thrown.

Is it a bug? I expected an IOException,  but AlreadyClosedException I
got, and AlreadyClosedException is a RuntimeException.

If not, why all other errors cause an IOException.

```
 @Test
 public void testConnectionLost() throws IOException{
           ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
           factory.setRequestedHeartbeat(60);
           factory.setHost("<your rabbitmq host>");


           Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
           Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
           connection.close();

           try {
                   channel.queueDeclare("queueName", false, false, false, null);
                   Assert.fail("Exception expected.");
           }catch (IOException e) {
                   //it will NOT reach here.
                   //Inner exception should be AlreadyClosedException
                   System.out.println(e);
           }catch (AlreadyClosedException e) {
                   // it will reach here.
                   System.out.println(e);

                   //this is strange!
                   //I expected IOException , but AlreadyClosedException I got.
                   //And AlreadyClosedException is a RuntimeException.
           }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your client loses the TCP connection to your broker, the connection is considered "closed". Therefore it is appropriate (and not a bug) for the client library to throw an `AlreadyClosedException`.

In other words, a connection is considered "closed" no matter how it got closed (either through a graceful manner or through an unexpected failure).